# working with libs of 64 bit system under 32 bit system

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-12.04, mercurial

I had a 64 bit ubuntu 10.04 system.I messed up with `ubuntu-desktop`,which was refusing me to login. So i have installed ubuntu 12.04 32 bit system through ISO image in a DVD, keeping  the same username.While installing, I have re-used the partitions of earlier system and chose same username as well to keep the data in `/home` intact.

I have installed `mercurial` through `sudo apt-get` on ubuntu 12.04.But when i am running it i am receiving this stack trace. I am sure mercurial is trying to access earlier 64 bit system.Because, i found that in `/usr/local/lib/` there are two python installations - 2.6 and 2.7.

Help needed in fixing this.

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 95, in _demandimport
    return _import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 114, in _demandimport
    mod = _origimport(name, globals, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 155, in <module>
    class Report(problem_report.ProblemReport):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 86, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 58, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 93, in <module>
    class ProblemReport(UserDict):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 36, in <module>
    mercurial.util.setbinary(fp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 86, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 58, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 67, in <module>
    statfiles = getattr(osutil, 'statfiles', platform.statfiles)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 86, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 58, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/osutil.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Comment: Its not possible to have gone from a 64-bit installation to a 32-bit installation even with Ubuntu.  You sure thats what you did?

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the question.Please go through once again.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
       I have found the answer,I have removed `/usr/local/lib/python2.6` and `python2.7` folders. I have copied `/usr/lib/python2.6` and `python2.7` over `/usr/local/lib/` location.That did the trick.

```
cp -Rp /usr/lib/python2.6  /usr/local/lib/
cp -Rp /usr/lib/python2.7   /usr/local/lib/
```